# Add comment in Django-cms page

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using Django-CMS and I'm looking for a simple way to add comments by user at the end of each page. Is the extension. Can the plugin and apphook help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's `comments` framework which is documented here:
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/